# htaccess - how to make subdomain from one of variable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

in file .htaccess i have a syntax:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*),([a-z0-9-_.]+),([a-z0-9-_.]+),([a-z0-9-_.]+)$ $4.php?n=$1&nazwa=$2&t=$3&v=$5 [L,NC,NS,NE]
```

`$4` is the name of file which i want to make a subdomain in my address.

- till now address is like that: `http://domain/name-of-film,100000,main,film,0`
- i want to make an address like that: `http://domain/film/name-of-film,100000,main,0`

thanks for any possible answer

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_.]+)/(.*),(.*),([a-z0-9-_.]+),([a-z0-9-_.]+)$ $1.php?n=$2&nazwa=$3&t=$4&v=$5 [L,NC,NS,NE]
```

Comment: i've tried this earlier but it returnes 404 Not Found The request /name-of-film,100000,main,0 was not found on this server. it seems like the subdomain (name of file) is not recognized.

Comment: @AdamS it works perfectly well on my machine, could I see your whole `.htaccess` file?

Comment: in my htaccess i have 3 lines which are responsible for making my address clearer
`RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*),([a-z0-9-_.]+),([a-z0-9-_.]+),([a-z0-9-_.]+)$ $4.php?n=$1&nazwa=$2&t=$3&v=$5 [L,NC,NS,NE]
RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*),([a-z0-9-_.]+),([a-z0-9-_.]+)$ $4.php?n=$1&nazwa=$2&t=$3 [L,NC,NS,NE]
RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*),(.*)$ $3.php?id=$2&n=$1 [L,NC,NS,NE]`

Comment: @AdamS do you have a folder on your site called '`film/`'?

Comment: no, folder not exist, this subddomain should be dynammicly make from variable which are the name of the file (ex. film)

Comment: @AdamS are you sure those 3 `RewriteRule`s are the only lines in your `.htaccess` file? Don't you have `RewriteEngine on` or any `RewriteCondition`s?

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*).(js|css)$ cache_gzip.php?file=$1.$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*/([^/,]*,.*) /$1 [L,R=301,NE]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.dobry-portal\.pl$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ http://www.dobry-portal.pl%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*),([a-z0-9-_.]+),([a-z0-9-_.]+),([a-z0-9-_.]+)$ $4.php?n=$1&nazwa=$2&t=$3&v=$5 [L,NC,NS,NE]
RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*),([a-z0-9-_.]+),([a-z0-9-_.]+)$ $4.php?n=$1&nazwa=$2&t=$3 [L,NC,NS,NE]
RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*),(.*)$ $3.php?id=$2&n=$1 [L,NC,NS,NE]`
redirect is disable